# IntelliJ Idea 2018.2 - File Status Highlights: red/brown

Tags: intellij-idea, module, configuration, pom.xml

I have the current status of my files in the folders coloured red/brown.
I tried to follow previous discussion on stackoverflow to solve the problem but without result.
How can get rid of the red colour of the file?
What is the correct settings?

[image]

with pom.xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>delta.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>books</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.Run</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and iml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_10">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.12" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Screenshot of my configuration of the project:

[image]

modules:

[image]

dependencies:

[image]

Comment: In my case, it is because the files are not added into your version control, e.g. Git.  Try to select the files, right click, and add them to version control.

Comment: @JohnZhang: I didn't add this project on github, it's only on my mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version control feature that marks files that hasn't been staged yet this color.

To remove this behaviour go to

Settings -> Version Control -> File Status Colors

where you can set colors for all statuses or disable them by removing the  checkmark from the "File status color" field.

[image]

Comment: This way you loos indication of unversioned files totally. I believe it is a wrong way to solve this. If you don't want some files to be highlighted as unversioned, add them to vcs ignore list instead

Comment: @Dmitriy Smirnov: Could you please explain how?

Comment: @DmitriySmirnov: by your suggest, now I have the name of the files in green colour !? There is a way to don't be connected to vcs?

Comment: add them to gitgnore (or other VCS ignore file). Green means they are scheduled for addition and it is not what you want. To disable VCS integration set the mapping in Settings | Version control to None

Answer (score 1):

This is because the files are not added into your version control, e.g. Git. Try to select the files, right click, and add them to version control. After that, they should turn into green.

Comment: they are already green :) There is a possibility to disable the version control?